# open view in center of iPad

Tags: ipad, window, center, popover

Sorry, I have a question. I don't know what type of window is the center window open in that can see in the image.

Can help me?

Thanks for your help!!

[image: view in center window]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just a regular modal UIView presented with the Form Sheet style.

The UIViewController class has a modalPresentationStyle property that determines the appearance of the view controller when it is presented modally. The different options for this property allow you to present the view controller so that it fills the entire screen, as before, or only part of the screen.

The different styles are UIModalPresentationFullScreen, UIModalPresentationPageSheet, and UIModalPresentationFormSheet.